# Convert text to fit the page (from commandline)

Tags: pdf, printing, conversion, text-formatting

How to scale short texts (from one word, up to couple of short lines) to fit the page (nice to have choice if centred or aligned to left etc) ?
 (from commandline)

Command:

`echo Audio | lpr -P Dymo450LabelWriter_network -o raw -o scaling=100`

Produces (wrong!!!) just small text in corner (I would like it to be scaled to page):

[image]

Please note that I use custom page formats (in above case it's 57mm x 32 mm).

Do you have something using pretty standard packages (simpler than generating LaTeX) ?

(Environment: printer works well with png, pdf, ps)

Comment: Nagh, not better than LaTeX,but I've tried with pure svg , also it seems hard: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15430189/544721

Comment: have you tried [glabels](http://glabels.org/)? it has GUI app and command-line `glabels-3-batch`  tool.  Works with full-page many-labels-per-page sheets (e.g. in a laser or inkjet printer) and with individual label printers like your Labelwriter 450.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I added clarification, that commandline "scriptable" solutions are within scope of my interest.

Comment: I assumed that, which is why i mentioned it has a command-line, scriptable tool.  I haven't looked too closely at it (I don't even have a label printer, I use an old manual dymo to label my disks etc with their serial numbers), but I expect if you examine the files that the GUI produces, it'll be some text format that can be generated with the usual tools (awk, perl, etc).

Comment: Yeah, as commandline scriptable you can make it an amswer to this question (not just comment) @cas ! :)

Comment: (well, when i say "old manual dymo", i mean it's not a printer, and has no USB/serial/parallel interface.  it's got an LCD screen and alpha-numeric and symbol buttons, and prints to thermal tape.  a Dymo LetraTag  XR.  i don't need to use it very often, otherwise i'd replace it with a  little printer like your LW450)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can do it. See the [examples under “Text Handling — Best Fit to Image”](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label_bestfit).

```
convert -background white -fill black -density 600x600 -size 1346x756 -gravity center label:'Audio' audio.pdf
```

It also supports multiline:

```
convert -background white -fill black -density 600x600 -size 1346x756 -gravity center label:'Audio\nCables' audio_cables.pdf
```

Output of first command:
[image]

Output of second command:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try `enscript`. It has many features, many of which do not interest you, but you can set a font-size and media size. It does not centre nor justify, but you can visualise the result with ghostview and amend your data. Try this:

```
cat <<\! >>~/.enscriptrc
# Media: name width height llx lly urx ury   bounding box lowleft upright
# 57mm x 32 mm converted to points:
Media: mylabel 161 90 0 0 161 90
!

echo 'hello and hello followed by bye bye' |
enscript -p - -h -B -M mylabel -f Helvetica-Bold@30 >out.ps
gv --media=mylabel out.ps
```

You can see the text being broken up into 2 pages of your given label size.

Output of proposed command:

page 1:
[image]
page 2: [image]

Answer (score 2):

[glabels](http://glabels.org/) has both a GUI editor (`glabels-3`) for creating `.glabels` files, and a `glabels-3-batch` program for printing previously created .glabels from the command line or script.

It supports "mail-merge" functionality from various file formats, including CSV.

The .glabels file is just `gzip`-compressed XML.  I created a simple file with `glabels-3` (one big text field with 7 lines of text in it).  After `gunzip`-ing the file, it looks like this:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Glabels-document xmlns="http://glabels.org/xmlns/3.0/">
  <Template brand="Dymo" part="99012" size="Other" width="35.9999mm" height="88.9998mm" description="Large Address Labels">
    <Meta category="label"/>
    <Meta category="mail"/>
    <Label-rectangle id="0" width="35.9999mm" height="88.9998mm" round="0mm" x_waste="0mm" y_waste="0mm">
      <Markup-margin size="0mm"/>
      <Layout nx="1" ny="1" x0="0mm" y0="0mm" dx="35.9999mm" dy="88.9998mm"/>
    </Label-rectangle>
  </Template>
  <Objects id="0" rotate="True">
    <Object-text x="1.33759mm" y="1.0501mm" w="86.1756mm" h="33.7488mm" justify="Left" valign="Top" auto_shrink="False" a0="1" a1="0" a2="0" a3="1" a4="0" a5="0">
      <Span color="0x000000ff" font_family="Sans" font_size="12" font_weight="Regular" font_italic="False" line_spacing="1">Line1<NL/>Line2<NL/>Line3<NL/>Line4<NL/>Line5<NL/>Line6<NL/>Line7</Span>
    </Object-text>
  </Objects>
  <Data/>
</Glabels-document>
```

Should be easy to generate with any XML tool or programming library, or even just print statements in `sh`, `awk`, or `perl`.